# Exchange server address list service failed to respond while creating mailboxes

Tags: exchange-2007, exchange

[old thread](https://serverfault.com/questions/266347/sid-changed-on-exchange-trust-is-broken-between-ad-and-exchange)

When creating mailboxes in new OU, the error "The Exchange server address list service failed to respond" is seen. Creating new mailboxes for already existing OU works fine.
Problem since V2V migration (from hyper v to esxi).

- Date and time is correct on exchange + the ad servers
- Test-ServiceHelath shows all services running

Running Best Practices Analyser:

> Organization incoming message size too high
>   Organization outgoing message size too high
>
> Offline Address book definition is missing
>   The 'msExchUseOAB' value for mailbox store 'Mailbox Database' on server VM02 is missing. This will cause offline address book errors for 3 users in this database.

Right after the (vmware converter) V2V conversion, I see this in events log:

> 9327 
>   OALGen skipped some entries in the offline address list '\Global Address List'.  To see which entries are affected, event logging for the OAL Generator must be set to at least medium. 
>   - PAAB Offline Address Book
>
> 9408 
>   OALGen failed to load the offline address book version 4 manifest file '\VM02\ExchangeOAB\9227b150-e6b2-4cae-ade1-2df2d81e9b67\oab.xml'. This indicates data tampering or disk problems. Restore files in this folder from the recent backup or clean up folder content and force a full OAB generation.
>
> 9109 
>   OALGen encountered an error ffffffff (internal ID 50509bc) while generating address list '\Global Address List'.  Check other logged events to see if this is a serious error. 
>   - PAAB Offline Address Book

What seem to be going on here? How can this affect only new mailboxes in new OUs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't if this is related or not to your problem, by I'd start by fixing those obviously address-book-related errors.

For the first one: go to the properties of the Mailbox Database, in the "Client Settings" tab, and configure the Offline Address Book this database's users should use (if you only have the default one, just select it).

For the other ones: force a full Offline Address Book rebuild using

```
Get-OfflineAddressBook | Update-OfflineAddressBook
```

Comment: Can I do this while users are using it, or should I do it night time?

Comment: The first step can be performed anytime, the second one can put some load on the server depending on the number of users and can block the download of updates to the offline address book for a while, but should not affect normal user activity at all.

Comment: I have two .edbs mounted where "Client access" tab exist: First Storage Group, called "Mailbox Database" hasnt got an offline address book configured. Second: Hosted Exchange Storage group, with 'Hosted Exchange Database' has got one out of total 13 available offline address books.

Comment: Second step was performed. I'll be watching the event logs too see if the error goes away

Comment: I still get errors in event log regarding the offline address lists, but now I can create new OUs and mailboxes - fully tested. Will create a separate thread for the Offline Address lists and their errors.